# Submit Value With Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I'm a stuck with the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeElement($parentDiv, $childDiv){


     if (document.getElementById($childDiv)) {    
          var child = document.getElementById($childDiv);
          var parent = document.getElementById($parentDiv);
          parent.removeChild($child);
     }
}
</script>

<a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"removeElement('$parent','$child');\">x</a>
```

This function deletes a child element, and its content, which works great client-side! But I am wanting to pass a value to the server, in the same instance, so the content of the element can be deleted from the mysql database too. I have no idea how to do this, so any suggestions will be very appreciated!

Notes: $child, and $parent are strings generated within the php file, that I use to give each element a unique ID.

Comment: I'm not a great server side programmer, but I'm picking stuff up quickly. I am a pretty good javascript programmer, if there is such a thing. Question for you: Can you, within the same removeElement function, send a cgi, restlike, or dynamic script tag request via XMLHttpRequest back to the server?

Comment: @jeremyosborne -> urmmm? I wouldnt have the slightest clue? I am a total noob when it comes to javascript.

Comment: are you using some clientside framework, Jquery, scriptaculos, moo tools. it all becomes super easy then.

Comment: We're starting a good comment thread here, but maybe we can get your question answered. @Ori has a point, it's very easy, but can you tell us what the url would look like were we to simply send a query to your CMS to delete the content?

Comment: @jeremyosborne - page.php?delete=elementID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your life easier, use jQuery or similar framework. Here's how you would do it in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.delete').click(function() {
        var link = $(this);
        var id = link.attr('id').replace('element_', '');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'handler.php',
            data: {
                element: id
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function() {
                link.remove();
                // Or link.closest('tr').remove() if you want to remove a table row where this link is
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="delete" id="element_20">Remove</a>
```

And handler.php:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element'])."'");
```

Always remember to escape database input!

If you're a total noob as you said, you probably won't understand all of this so I suggest you read something about jQuery's AJAX capabilities and about overall development using jQuery or similar JavaScript framework.

Comment: Hi, Thanks!! It all works fine, except instead of the element being deleted, only the link is being deleted? I tried link.closest('tr').remove(), and just changed the tr, to div... but its not working? Any suggestions?

Comment: Depends on what you want to delete. If the delete link is inside the element you are trying to delete, then .closest('div'); should work. If it's not, you must try something else. Check out jQuery's documentation on traversing and selectors on http://docs.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say I want to delete an entity using a ID

JQUERY - $.post()
This is an easy way to send a simple POST request to a server without having to use the more complex $.ajax function. It allows a single callback function to be specified that will be executed when the request is complete (and only if the response has a successful response code). [Jquery post docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)

On the server assuming you have an open database connection.

mysql_query("DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID = ".$_POST['ID']);

more [on mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) found here

EDIT:

So the following will only remove the element when the ajax post is complete. Note the first arg is the url to the script that will take the action , second is the data to be sent, in this case the ID post value will be {child.id} and the third is a anon inline callback function that will take action to remove the element client side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeElement($parentDiv, $childDiv){
if (document.getElementById($childDiv)) {
          var child = document.getElementById($childDiv);
          var parent = document.getElementById($parentDiv);  
          $.post('{URLTOSCRIPT}', 'ID=$child.id',function () { parent.removeChild($child); });

}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! So how would I integrate this into the existing code without breaking the removeElement() functionality? Could you give me an example please?

Comment: Thanks again! I am receiving an error from firebug *missing formal parameter using your snippet. Also URLTOSCRIPT -? Do I replace this with url to the page that will handle data? Sorry if my noobness is annoying

Comment: Yes replace urltoscript inclusive of the {} and replace in the second param $child.id with the actual value required. ie ID=3 or ID=SWK01 ...

Comment: Sorry I take so long... I couldnt get your snippet to work. It doesnt post, and it returns the error *missing formal parameter*

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function, you'd want to put your PHP variables in tags like so:

`<?php echo $parent; ?>`

and

`<?php echo $child; ?>`

In the function definition, you will want to get rid of the PHP style variables and use something like:

`function removeElement(parentDiv, childDiv) {
//CODE
}`

Comment: The JS function is sitting in a PHP page of functions. It still outputs as your code would suggest to.